# Replace html css style with condition from css file

Tags: html, css, conditional-statements

I have this problem and I don't know how to fix it. In my project many html files have defined for div an width style, for example:

```
<div style="width:200px" id="boom">/*****/</div>
```

In css file if I put a condition like:

```
`div#boom{width:auto !important;}`
```

is ignored because style is defined in html for that div and from what I know html condition beat css condition.
How is possible to fix that? I don't want to edit all html pages because I would take a long time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing something wrong. Because `!important` makes the style the highest priority, so it always use the `width: auto;` and not the inline CSS.

An live example that this works: http://tinkerbin.com/wzrFiyaq 
And a tutorial: http://css-tricks.com/override-inline-styles-with-css/

Comment: @Jared you can do it without the [style] attribute selector.

Answer (score 1):

```
div[style] {
   width:auto !important;
   }​
```

Comment: why is the word auto after the closing brace?

Comment: Yes, that link doesn't say anything about `auto`, it's talking about `!important`...